# Div atrapalha o Link

Tags: css

Tenho as seguintes DIVs:

```
<section id="cidades">
    <div class="listacidade">ESCOLHA UMA OPÇÃO</div>
    <div class="listacidade"><a href="../zz"><img src="<? echo base_url(); ?>site/modules/entrada/images/cidade_fozdoiguacu.jpg" width="250" height="120" alt=""/></a></div>
    <div class="fade-down listacidade"><a href="../x"><img src="<? echo base_url(); ?>site/modules/entrada/images/cidade_curitiba.jpg" width="250" height="120" alt=""/></a></div>
    <div class="fade-down listacidade"><a href="../y"><img src="<? echo base_url(); ?>site/modules/entrada/images/cidade_santacatarina.jpg" width="250" height="120" alt=""/></a></div>
</section>

<div class="texto-interno">
    texto do site
</div>
```

Com os seguintes CSS:

```
.listacidade 
{
    margin-left: 40%;
    margin-right: 30px;
    margin-top: 15px;
    float: left;
}

.texto-interno{
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #656565;
    margin-top: 60px;
    margin-right: 30px;
    line-height: 40px;
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 999;
}
```

Mas o caso é: que por mais que eu tenha link nas imagens... Elas ficam "sem link", como se uma div sobrepusesse a outra. Não sei o que está incorreto

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O elemento `<a>` por padrão possui o tipo de display como *inline*, o que permite-o ser incorporado em textos e em conjunto com outras palavras. Mas elementos inline não aceitam certas propriedades existentes em elementos de bloco (como `margin`, `width` e `height`), e isto que está afetando os links no seu caso (por ser inline ele não pega o tamanho da imagem dentro).

Para resolver o problema, simplesmente mude o tipo do elemento `<a>` no CSS de `inline` para `block`. Exemplo:

```
.listacidade a{
    display: block; /* todos os links dentro da lista agora são de bloco */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Você esta colocando link apenas na imagem, não na DIV em si.
Pra que funcione você precisa colocar um tamanho pra DIV também e caso queira que o link fique na div toda não só na imagem(caso ela for menor que a div)coloque o link antes da div.